# How to properly include credits for the author, location, date and time?

Tags: style, formatting, structure

I'm working on an amateur article about various topics and want to include my name (as the author), location of where I'm currently writing the article, and the current date and time.

I've seen many journalists use a syntax similar to the one below in their news articles:

```
ISTANBUL, July 20, 2020
```

I'm not sure whether this is correct or not but as I remember, this was the syntax they were using for their articles. What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to the one above, but with the addition of my name.

Another example I saw on the internet is this:

[image: Example]

But I can't use such syntax as I'm not writing something this serious with sections, editions and nor for a newspaper.

- What's the proper way to include such credits?
- Should I include these at the end of my article, or at the top, right below my title like many news articles?

Comment: To me, these look like two completely different things. I'm not exactly sure about the first one without being able to see it in context, but it seems to be either a section heading with the purpose of telling us where the article is taking place, or part of a byline. The second one is a citation, referring to a different article, so that's probably not what you want.

Comment: It also depends what you want this for - when you say amateur, do you mean only for yourself, or to appear in a publication (albeit one that doesn't pay)?

Comment: @DM_with_secrets Yeah the second one isn't the one I want. I never looked at it with that perspective, rather I already know how citations are done but, strangely I didn't notice it.

Comment: @DM_with_secrets With amateur I mean only for myself.

Comment: Many journals include a brief bio for the author. If you are publishing these on your own website, you could include a link to your bio page. If you want the individual articles to get visibility on their own, include the brief bio at the end of each article, separated out a bit or a different font, etc. For examples, go to Medium (or many other sites with articles) and scroll down to the bottom. If you are writing articles in a particular subject area, check online journals on the same subject and see how they do it.